# Sqllite database access from real device(Mobile)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How to access Sqlite database from mobile? I tried using the following link but "the package name is unknown" error message displayed.

http://droidista.blogspot.in/2012/11/quick-tip-pulling-sqlite-db-file-from.html

Comment: What is the package name of your app? And what command are you typing?

Comment: I use these command,My package name is specified as unknown                              
 adb -d shell
 run-as jfh.auctionhall
 cat /data/data/ jfh.auctionhall/databases/Auction>/sdcard/Auction